# What is the name of the theme song at the end of episode 12 of Tokyo Ghoul?

Tags: theme-song, tokyo-ghoul

With the start of the second season of the anime, I've rewatched some of the previous episodes of Tokyo Ghoul. Does anyone know the name of the song that plays at the end of episode 12?

Answer (score 6):

The song that plays at the end of episode 12 is the same as the opening theme song. It is called "Unravel", and is by TK.

[image: "Unravel" cover]

Lyrics and more information can be found [on the *Tokyo Ghoul* Wiki](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Unravel).

The full version of the song can be heard [on YouTube](http://youtu.be/uMBT5IHlC6k?t=5s).

Answer (score -2):

The song that plays at the end of [Tokyo Ghoul](https://tokyoghoulmask.com) episode 12 is "Unravel by TK". I remember getting hooked to this song when I last saw it.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Unless you are going to add new or relevant information to the previous answer, please avoid posting duplicate answers. Thanks!